# using functions across multiple scripts/functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a handful of js scripts in jquery:

```
vars.js
 $(function(){
      function yesOrNo(val){
          if (val == "yes"){
              return "yes";
          }
          if (val == "no"){
              return "no";
          }
 });
```

---

```
scripts1.js


 /// include(vars.js) <-- what would go here?

   $(function(){
       
       var var1 = "yes";
       var test1 = yesOrNo(var1);
       alert(test1);
   });
```

---

```
scripts2.js

  
 /// include(vars.js) <-- what would go here?

   $(function(){

       var var2 = "no";
       var test2 = yesOrNo(var2);
       alert(test2);
   });
```

---

```
scripts3.js

 /// include(vars.js) <-- what would go here?

   $(function(){
       var var3 = "yes";
       var test3 = yesOrNo(var3);
       alert(test3);
   });
```

How can i call the function yesOrNo from a different scripts.js page?

Comment: Just make sure your shared script file `vars.js` is loaded before the others. And remove the `$(function(){ }` around the function `yesOrNo`, you don't need to wait for the DOM to load to declare the function `yesOrNo`

Comment: thanks.  i just threw this together for this question.  the real scripts are far more detailed.  your first comment was what i was looking for. thanks again!

Comment: @RyanWilson he has to remove `$(function() {})` around `yesOrNo`, but NOT for DOM loading matters. `yesOrNo` is scoped to the `function()` where it is defined, so it will never be available in the global scope, regardless of the scripts order.

Comment: @cheesyMan There's still no reason to wait for the DOM to load but thanks for giving us your 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another file add `type="module"` parameters in your main code, then add the line `import {yesOrNo} from './vars.js';` in your code.
Then, in the vars.js file, add the function as `export function yerOrNo`, not `function yesOrNo`.

My edit of your code:

vars.js

```js
export function yesOrNo(val){
  if (val == "yes"){
    return "yes";
  }
  if (val == "no"){
    return "no";
  }
}
```

main.js

```js
import {yesOrNo} from './vars.js'
$(function(){
  var var2 = "no";
  var test2 = yesOrNo(var2);
  alert(test2);
});
```

On your html call `main.js` like that

```html
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```